# What is parabolic temperature distribution?

Tags: laplace-method, parabolic-pde

In building up mathematical model to solve a problem, I have just encountered with this one: "Regarding the temperature distribution in a long box with a rectangular domain. At the top the temperature is ***parabolic*** with 10 degrees at both corner and 25 degrees in the middle..."

I don't understand what is the parabolic temperature distribution? Do we have any equation for it?

Thank you very much and best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

It seems that the temperature can be represented by a parabola of equation $t=ax^2+bx+c$, with the parameters $a,b,c$ such that $t(0)=t(l)=10$  and $t(l/2)=25$, where $l$ is the length of the top side of the rectangular region.  Can you find the parameters?

Comment: Sorry . I edit :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I understand your explanation. I will think about it !